# Is there any way to create a delay in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, delay

I want to display an image for 1 second and then disappear it. The code i'm trying to use is:

```
    PictureBox4.Visible = True
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) ' 1 second delay
    PictureBox4.Visible = False
```

But so far it's not working, is there a way to make this code works or any other methods to implement a delay  in vb.net?

Comment: [Timer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer) -- [Task.Delay() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay)

Comment: Thanks Jimi, gonna check it out

Comment: Define "not working."  What is it doing?

Comment: @Craig when I run it the image is not appearing, and I checked the properties of the image and they are all fine. But when the progam is running there's no image.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code isn't working is because `Sleep` is tying up the UI thread and the control is never redrawn. So technically the `Visible` property is being changed, it is just that the user never sees the change.

You have a couple of options. One is to use a System.Timers.Timer ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer)) and set the `AutoReset` to false and the `Interval` to 1,000. Before you start the timer you would show the control and then in the Timer's `Elapsed` event you would hide the control. Here is a quick example:

```vb
Private ReadOnly _timer As Timers.Timer

Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    _timer = New Timers.Timer() With {
        .AutoReset = False,
        .Interval = 1000,
        .SynchronizingObject = Me
    }
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' create an event handler for the Elapsed event
    AddHandler _timer.Elapsed, Sub() PictureBox4.Hide()

    ' show the control then start the timer
    PictureBox4.Show()
    _timer.Start()
End Sub
```

**Update**

Per JMcIlhinney's suggestion, I'm setting the `SynchronizingObject` property so that you don't have to call the `Invoke` method when hiding the control.

Comment: Use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer, so you don't need to Invoke() anything in a different Thread and you have the same result. BTW, suppose you need to use this Timer more than once, to perform the same action... can you remove the handlers you're adding?

Comment: Just like a `FileSystemWatcher`, a `Timers.Timer` has a `SynchronizingObject` property. If you assign the form or some other control to that then the `Timer` will raise its `Elapsed` event on the UI thread. Presumably you chose a `Timers.Timer` because it can be configured to raise its `Elapsed` event only once, but it's no more code to simply call `Stop` in the `Tick` event handler of a `Windows.Forms.Timer`. You can also add either `Timer` to the form in the designer and set `SynchronizingObject` automatically, although the `Timers.Timer` is not in the Toolbox by default.

Comment: @Jimi - implementing JMcIlhinney's advice resolved the need to call invoke. As far as not removing the handler, the reason I didn't in my example is because presumably the OP is toggling the visibility of the control multiple times and it would be inefficient to add/remove the handler in that situation. So I'm comfortable letting the form dispose of the handler when it closes.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - thank you for the feedback regarding the `SynchronizingObject` property, I've updated my post to include it. You are correct in your assumption as to why I chose the `Timers.Timer` class over the `Forms.Timer` class. Just as a personal matter, I prefer to use the former over the latter when I need a simple "wait" action.

Comment: @Jimi, I hope you appreciated the reference to the `FileSystemWatcher` because that was for you. ;-)

Comment: Since you're using a `SynchronizationContext` to marshal to the UI Thread, now you have the same functionality of a System.Windows.Forms.Timer. There's no need at all to add and remove the handler. @jmcilhinney Yes, I noticed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    PictureBox4.Visible = True
    Application.DoEvents()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    PictureBox4.Visible = False
```